# How are sortals different than types?

Tags: metaphysics, types

The criteria for a sortal from Wikipedia:

> - gives a criterion for counting the items of that kind
> - gives a criterion of identity and non-identity among items of that kind
> - gives a criterion for the continued existence of an item of that kind
> - answers the question "what is it?" for things of that kind
> - specifies the essence of things of that kind
> - does not apply to parts of things of that kind

That seem like the things I would also need to know to know what things to regard as tokens of a given type.

So how do the concepts of sortals and of tokens differ from each other?

Answer (score 6):

Sortals are words. Types are logical groupings. Otherwise they are very similar. The sort is a type, but the sortal is a term in a language.

Comment: You mean to say that *sortals* denote the words that denote specific types. E.g. *Chair* is a sortal for the type that includes all tokens of chairs?

Comment: yep a "sortal" is a word that tells you what sort the thing you're talking about belongs too. There are different kinds of sortals as well.

Comment: So why is it limited to count nouns? I mean 'water' is a sort of thing.

Comment: "water" is a mass term. "This is a water" is ungrammatical.

Comment: True. But how is that philosophically interesting?

Comment: Well it's a grammatical point--sortals are just a particular kind of word, remember. And they've got specific kinds of grammar associated with them, at least in all the natural languages I'm familiar with. (not a representative sample) To get some philosophical mileage out of the concept of a sortal, you're going to need independent philosophical arguments. You might note that there are special "substance" sortals that play foundational roles in our cognitive equipment for describing and explaining the world. But that's a separate philosophical argument.

Comment: *You might note that there are special "substance" sortals that play foundational roles in our cognitive equipment for describing and explaining the world.* That's what I'm interested in. Would you mind elaborating on that in your answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to discuss much more today due to work. I recommend, however, David Wiggins's book *Sameness and Substance Renewed* for a very lucid discussion of this issue.